# Select dropdown with f:field (fields plugin) in Grails 3

Tags: grails, plugins

I'm trying to generate a select drop down with an option preselected (based on params) using the fields plugin. The code below generates a select box with the proper elements and everything works except it doesn't add "selected" to the option tag. It seems to be ignoring my widget- attributes.

From what I understand the fields plugin will pick g:select in this case by default if not overridden, and you can use widget- to pass arguments to it.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<f:field bean="specialUser" property="user" label="user.label" widget-optionKey="id" widget-value="${params.user?.id?:value?.id}"/>
```

Link to the fields documentation:http://grails3-plugins.github.io/fields/snapshot/guide/single.html#

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have done what I wanted, computed specialUserList from the controller. Though it would've been nice to utilize the "widget-" to do this form me.

```
<f:field bean="specialUser" property="user" label="user.label">
    <g:select id="user" name="user.id" optionKey="id" class="span-8 margin-bottom-none" from="${specialUserList}" noSelection="${['null': message(code: 'common.list.select')]}" value="${params.user?.id}"/>
</f:field>
```